# multiple modal with same data-target in one page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a bootrap modal. I have like five modals, and when I open the first modal, the rest of modals get opened too. How to make it specific when I click the modal without to have to create more class or id  on data-target?

```
<button class="btn btn-yellow detail"  data-toggle="modal" data-target=".detail">
  detail
</button>
<div class="modal fade detail" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi eos aut recusandae quos quisquam sint, veniam molestiae magnam fuga. Animi recusandae quis pariatur provident itaque, fugiat non minus nobis repellendus.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-yellow detail"  data-toggle="modal" data-target=".detail">
  detail
</button>
<div class="modal fade detail" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi eos aut recusandae quos quisquam sint, veniam molestiae magnam fuga. Animi recusandae quis pariatur provident itaque, fugiat non minus nobis repellendus.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The data-target for your button should be to an ID specific for the modal you want to open.  Currently, the data-target is opening any model with the detail class.

Try this, for example:

```
<button class="btn btn-yellow detail"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#detail1">
  detail
</button>
<div id="detail1" class="modal fade detail" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi eos aut recusandae quos quisquam sint, veniam molestiae magnam fuga. Animi recusandae quis pariatur provident itaque, fugiat non minus nobis repellendus.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-yellow detail"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#detail2">
  detail
</button>
<div id="detail2" class="modal fade detail" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi eos aut recusandae quos quisquam sint, veniam molestiae magnam fuga. Animi recusandae quis pariatur provident itaque, fugiat non minus nobis repellendus.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```